# unable to run the android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been learning about google maps api from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/) and did exactly what was said..
My `mainactivity` code is as follows:

```
package com.map.place;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
}
```

The `main.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="0Ove92B2I7FZi4SR2YX89jA374Wcg6-cJ33VwUg"
/>
```

lastly the `manifest` file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.map.place"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
                  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

The logcat console was showing as follows:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  975): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  975): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activ
ity ComponentInfo{com.map.place/com.map.place.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotF
oundException: com.map.place.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoade
r[/data/app/com.map.place-2.apk]
```

I don't know what was wrong, but this was displaying `Sorry, the app stopped unexpectedly`.
I was running it on an `avd` with `2.3.3` platform and API level `10`. Plz correct me...

Comment: Can you give us some more information from LogCat or the Eclipse console?

Comment: actually i am using netbeans.. and it was compiling fine... the console output has been added..

Comment: Check [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) and post the logcat output you have received.

Comment: @Rajesh I found this peculiar line.. and i think probably this was the error!!! can u plz help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use your code and make it runnable, Below is running code. Only change your Map API key : Try it...and use emulator and android version with google API like android 2.2 google API
It also include zooming controls: 
main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#008000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0twJXMQDHBfxjMnb77nwRzKs29kGZdRkcG3_Z8Q" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
       /> 


</RelativeLayout>
```

your manifest.xml file :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.map.place"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />
 </application>
 </manifest>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.map.place;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.LayoutParams;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity{

//===========
MapView mapView;
public static String latitude,longitude;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.setSatellite(false);
LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.zoom);
View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls();

zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, new     
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
mapView.invalidate();

}

// Below is the code when the user presses the number 3 on the keyboard the
// map  will zoom in into the next level. Pressing number 1 will zoom out one
// level.

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
MapController mc = mapView.getController();
switch (keyCode) {
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:
    mc.zoomIn();
    break;
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
    mc.zoomOut();
    break;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return false;
}

}
//By Umesh Suryawanshi
```

Comment: Finally the code which u gave has worked...!!! thanx alot... i am a beginner actually, but i wil try to resolve the prob. with my prev. code for sure..in future... :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `<uses-library>` tag is in the wrong place. It should be in the `<application>` tag, not an `<activity>` tag. Try using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.map.place"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Also, make sure you use an emulator with the Google APIs installed.

Answer (score 0):

1) check your Target is Google api 2.3.3 .

2) check your key is correct.

3) check your manifest like this.

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".ShowMapActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>

   </application>
```

4) if you not get solution then find again your key and use it.